# Requests in parallel generate inserts instead of upates in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a service that should count how many times a user logs. If I make 3 requests in parallel, I end up in the database with this :

| Name | Requests |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 |
| Jane | 1 |
| Jane | 1 |

Instead of

| Name | Requests |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 3 |

The name is **not** a primary key.
The sleep is for demonstration purposes only, for a slow connection to the DB.

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Long getRequestNumber(String name) {
       UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByName(name);

       if (userEntity == null) {
          Thread.sleep(10000);
          UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
          userEntity.setName(name);
          userEntity.setReqNumber(1L);
          userRepository.saveAndFlush(userEntity);
          return 1L;
        } else {
          userEntity.setReqNumber(userEntity.getReqNumber() + 1);
          userRepository.saveAndFlush(userEntity);
          return userEntity.getReqNumber();
       }
  }
}


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long> {
      UserEntity findByName(String name);
}



  @Data
  @Builder
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "user")
  public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "req_number")
  private Long reqNumber;

}
```

---

Later edit :

This seems to work but I am courius if anyone has a better idea ?

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ) @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "30000")})
  UserEntity findByName(String name);
}
```

Comment: this behavior is not surprising since you are sleeping for 10 seconds before inserting the new UserEntity

Comment: The sleep is for demo purpose only

Comment: I understand that. Even without the sleep this behavior could occasionally occur

Comment: You should look up the concept of _isolation levels_ and determine how those constraints relate to your requirements.

Comment: I tried

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long> {

      @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ) @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "3000")})
      UserEntity findByName(String name);
}

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want multiple rows with the same user name, you should put a unique constraint on that column.

With the unique constraint, only one of the parallel first requests for a user will succeed. The other will fail with a constraint violation. This makes sense, it's similar to creating new user accounts with the same username simultaneously - only one user can (and should) succeed.

To increment the counter it's better to let the database handle that transactionally:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserEntity u set u.Requests = u.Requests + 1 where u.name = :name")
int updateUserSetStatusForName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: Sorry, it was .setName(name)

Comment: Puting a unique contraint generates an error and that request will be rejected.

Comment: Correct. But if you want to eliminate the risk of getting multiple entries for one user that's a solution.

Comment: I tried:


 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRepository, Long> {

      @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ) @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "3000")})
      UserEntity findByName(String name);
}